# Is it safe to put control char in string?

Tags: c

```
char *a = malloc(10);
memset(a, 10, 0);
a[0]= 'a';
a[1]= 6;
a[2]= 'b';
printf("%s\n", a); // prints ab
a[0]= 'a';
a[1]= 27;
a[2]= 'b';
printf("%s\n", a); // print a
return 1;
```

Is it safe to put control char in string? like in strcpy, etc..

Comment: That would need to be `0x27` for an apostrophe (unless you actually wanted `esc`)

Comment: Safe in what sense, exploitable?? It's just bytes. Just be careful, if you're concerned with portability, because not every terminal understands the same control sequences; consider using a library like [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C strings are NUL-terminated sequences of `char`s (bytes). Nothing more. Therefore, the control characters have no special meaning to the language or to `strcpy`.

Functions that care about the contents of strings will define which characters have special meanings.